# How to check whether user opened email?

Tags: asp.net, handler

I am trying to figure out when the user opens an email that i sent to him. I am sending an html email with an image in it. This image is handled by a generic handler. At the moment this handler is not hit. Is this a good way of achieving my goal?

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\temp\Desert.jpg");
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/bmp";
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
        }
```

the email body looks like this:

```
"<html><head><title></title></head><body><form name='form1' method='post' action='Default.aspx'><div><img id='Image1' src='ImageHandler.ashx?img=1' style='border-width:0px;' /></div></form></body></html>";
```

Comment: This may not be 100% perfect. AFAIK most of the email clients block images first and they are loaded on demand.

Comment: I don't know ASP, so I'll just comment: Spying on email readers is generally considered bad taste as it implicates privacy issues.  That said, there are ways in the mail system to request (note: not require) a notification of the mail being opened, and that should be preferred to a privacy-invasive image trick.

Comment: Things like this make me so glad my email programs don't even try to load such images. It's *none of your business* whether and when I read my email. That's my opinion, anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a couple of years ago I was faced with the same issue. I used your same exact approach, although this was a business requirement, so it was implicit for every member of the company to allow images coming from this specific email address. So every time someone opened an email, the generic handler would change something on the database, and we knew who opened an email. This was limited somewhat though. People using Outlook had to Double Click the email in order for this to work. Previewing the email was not enough for some reason I can't recall at the moment. This is kind of a trick though, so if this is not a Company's email, your best bet would be to actually send a hyperlink. Those interested in it will click on it and you will be able to see who actually saw your email. If not, I would not recommend this approach, cause as ibid mentioned this is kind of privacy-invasive. Good luck on your quest!

Answer (score 0):

There is no perfect solution for this as per my knowledge. I came across a nice article on this, though I have not implemented it but I think this may help you.

Here is the link for article

http://www.emailarchitect.net/eagetmail/sdk/html/object_report.htm

Answer (score 0):

Due to increasing privacy concerns most email clients are blocking access to external data by default, although the user can opt out of this behavior. The only way you can be sure whether the user has opened your email or not is by having them access some content on your server and log all the requests for that particular content, since most email clients are blocking Images the email marketing companies are trying to use other ways to track [like embedding iframes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_beacons#E-mail_web_bugs) in the email etc.,

Any technique still relies on the condition that the user has to access some content on the senders server, and with the ever increasing privacy issues, i don't think there will be a reliable way to track email messages in future

Answer (score 0):

You can never be sure that the user is actually viewing the image, but it might be an idea to make sure the image is actually linked to your web site:

```
<img id='Image1' src='http://yourserver.com/ImageHandler.ashx?img=1' style='border-width:0px;' />
```